# Got the error while installing packages in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, installation

```
PS E:\web dev 2024\threads> & npm install @clerk/nextjs @uploadthing/react mongoose svix uploadthing
Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:15
+ & npm install  <<<< @clerk/nextjs @uploadthing/react mongoose svix uploadth
ing
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecord 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

got this error while installing new packages in nextjs

Answer (score 0):

I removed the ampersand (&):

```
npm install @clerk/nextjs @uploadthing/react mongoose svix uploadthing
```

The error went away but it kept hanging. So I just broke it down to:

```
npm install @clerk/nextjs
```

and

```
npm install @uploadthing/react mongoose svix uploadthing
```

This fixed the issue. However, I will recommend installing your packages seperately for better control and management.